# Python - proc.wait() return code differs in windows 7 and 8

Tags: python-2.7

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(commandText, shell=True)
return_code = proc.wait()
if (return_code != 0):
    print "Failed to execute command"
```

In Windows 7, above snippet works perfect and return_code is 0 (Success)

In Windows 8, commandText executed successfully but return_code is 255 and control goes inside if loop.

1. How does the return_code differs in Windows 7 & 8?
2. Does return_code 255 indicate successful execution of commandText?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: What was the value of commandText?

Comment: Thats a DOS command specific for an exe application. When ran the same in DOS command line interface manually worked just fine.